# Design pattern for scheduling a large number of notifications

Tags: sql, notifications

I'm looking for a design pattern for a notification system. The notifications could be phone calls, SMS or email that would occur at a specific time for 1-many users. The notification process would be triggered by an internal event. A typical scenario would look like:

```
After the event is triggered...

Call - person A at 03:00:00 (attempt 1)
Call - person B at 03:00:05 (attempt 1)
Call - person C at 03:01:00 (attempt 1)
Call - person A at 03:05:00 (attempt 2)
Call - person B at 03:05:05 (attempt 2)
Call - person C at 03:06:00 (attempt 2)
...
Person A answered on attempt 3. Cancel all pending notifications for the event.
```

---

Design #1.1

Have a table that contains the information for the notification. After the event is triggered all the notifications for the first attempt for each user will be prescheduled and inserted into the table. A service will continuously query the table to get any notifications that should be currently processed. When a notification should be processed it will be deleted from the table and next notification attempt will be inserted into the table. The service will offload work to another service to perform the notification. Pending notifications for an event can be canceled by deleting them from the table.

Pros:

- Simple design
- Service is lightweight

Cons:

- Table is constantly queried. Doesn't seem like the most efficient way to do so.

Notes:

- Added suggestions Remus Rusanu

---

Other designed and comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pre-schedule all notifications. You only need to pre-schedule next notification. As part of handling the notification, you schedule the next attempt. This not only gets rid of the need to delete pending notifications, but more importantly makes handling delays possible. Think about if service is down for 10 minutes and then restarts, what do you do, do you call Person A attempt 2 *and* Person A attempt 3, since they're both overdue?

> Table is constantly queried

That is what databases are designed to handle. You just need to make sure the queries are efficient. I recommend you read [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/), and specially the part about Pending Queues. Make sure you don't mix state and events, keeps queues for events only, not for state.